# How to write a Foreach loop statement in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I tried to write a Foreach loop statement in ejs but it kept giving me an error message saying "songs.foreach is not a function"

```js
<% songs.foreach(function(song){ %>
    <li><%= song.name %> - <%= song.year %></li>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Array.prototype.forEach() is the correct syntax. Please correct 'forEach' spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript prototype is:

```
Array.prototype.forEach()
```

Your code should be:

```
<% songs.forEach(function(song){ %>
    <li><%= song.name %> - <%= song.year %></li>
<% }) %>
```